# Query on SQL Server view extremely slow with Entity Framework and linq

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, linq, view

I have the following situation: I have a view on my database which joins 5 tables together. I mapped this view in the EDMX to query it. And all record in my view is 200000 record.

I have a function like this

```
List<MyView> Function(EnumStatus statusSearch)
{
    return Context.MyView.Where(c => c.Status == statusSearch)).ToList();
}
```

When calling this function in my code like this

```
Function(EnumStatus.SuccessPayment)
```

the execution is extremely slow, something like 2 minutes or even more. but if I hardcode the `statusSearch` with `EnumStatus.SuccessPayment` in query like this

```
List<MyView> Function(EnumStatus statusSearch)
{
     return Context.MyView.Where(c => c.Status == EnumStatus.SuccessPayment)).ToList();
}
```

the query ran in less than 1 second.

Comment: which version is the SQL server?

Comment: sql server 2014

Comment: Have you define index on Status field ?

Comment: You mean from a fresh state, if you modify the method to hard-code the enum it is fast, but using the parameter is slow? That seems inconceivable. :)  Set a breakpoint on that line and run a profiler against the DB. (I.e. ExpressProfiler) Ensure this is an isolated DB with nothing else running on it to reduce any noise from other queries. When you step over the .ToList() you should see the SQL query in the profiler & execution time. How many queries appear? If 1 query, copy it to Ent. Mgr and execute with an execution plan.  Try again with the variable substitution.